# Spyder not finding pytrends

Tags: python, virtualenv, spyder, miniconda

I installed spyder on windows using the standalone installer (as recommended). I want to install the pytrends module so I installed miniconda and followed the steps [here](https://docs.spyder-ide.org/5/faq.html#using-packages-installer) to create a virtual environment for spyder and pointed spyder to that environment.
Finally, to install pytrends, I pointed conda to conda-forge and installed pytrends using conda install pytrends.

I restart the kernel, restart spyder, but I keep getting the error

> File "C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_4256/657856607.py", line 1, in 
> import pytrends
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytrends'

I'm on windows 10.

Comment: Answering for anyone who has a similar problem.  I uninstalled spyder, anaconda, python and reinstalled anaconda and used jupyter from anaconda. I ran conda install -c conda_forge pytrends in an anaconda prompt and jupyer was able to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Rename the file you want to run to something other than pytrends.py